# Add "about:blank" to Azure Mobile Service CORS whitelist

Tags: azure, webview, azure-mobile-services, windows-rt

I am trying to load content in a WebView in my Windows Phone 8.1 RT app. As per requirement, I need to fetch the content from database and render it in the WebView. The content is essentially an HTML document (with inline javascript and CSS) saved as a string in database. It also makes connection with mobile service.

I have added `*` in my mobile service's CORS whitelist. I also added `null` after discovering that it was required for the app's android and iOS counterparts.

I am using `NavigateToString()` method of WebView. It is not able to fetch data from azure because it sends `about:` as origin in the request header (possibly from `about:blank`). I need to add `about:` in whitelist but it won't allow because it says it is not a valid hostname. I added `about*` with no success. What should I add in CORS whitelist now, considering I already added `*`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming (slightly) that this is a WinJS application.  It actually has nothing to do with Azure or your Mobile Service.  It's got everything to do with the requirements within a WebView.

Review: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx

That link provides the yes/no for your request - in a WebView you are doing a Web context.  Note explicitly that you are doing Cross-Domain XHR requests are those are explicitly forbidden.